# What's the name of redirecting mysite.com/page to sd.othersite.com + hide sd.othersite.com red

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, redirect, subdomain, domain-name

I remember reading this was possible but don't remember the details anymore.

When a user visits `mysite.com/page` I want him to see the content that's showing on some other website's subdomain `sd.othersite.com`, yet I don't want him to realize that this content is not on `mysite.com/page`. I still want him to see `mysite.com/page` in the URL.

My registrar is GoDaddy. Can someone remind me at least what this type of routing is called, and any extra info on how to set it up would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Stealth URL Redirection/Domain Cloaking - http://www.abcseo.com/seo-book/domain-cloaking.htm